# Rename multiple files from a predefined directory to another directory

Tags: spacemacs, helm

I want to have a function, which moves a file or optionally multiple marked files from one directory to a different directory in some parent folder.
I managed to design a script which does the main things:

```
(defun multiple-rename (candidate)
(loop for cand in (helm-marked-candidates)
      do
      (spacemacs/rename-file cand)))
(defun move-from-downloads ()
  "helm interface to copy files from downloads"
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources `(
                   ((name . "My org files")
                    (candidates . ,(f-entries "~/Dropbox/Documents"))
                    (action . (("Rename" . multiple-rename))))
                   )))
```

The feature which is not present yet, which I would like to have is having some specified parent folder path for a target directory of renaming.

In other words, spacemacs/rename-file takes the file to rename as an argument and if it is not getting an a second argument which is here the case put up the prompt to select a filename where the files should be moved, the path in this prompt is however the path of the current buffer. Instead I would like to have the default path, which pops up in the prompt for renaming to be something different, e.g. `home/mydefaultrenamepath`. Would be happy to hear some solution, it doesn't need to use spacemacs/rename file, only the flow of having helm candidates to select and then standard directory to move files into (which should be able to be altered).

Comment: I would forego writing a function and instead use `dired`: set `dired-dwim-target` to `t`, open the first directory in one window, open the second directory in a second window, mark all the files you want to rename with `m` (or through  a more automated procedure: `dired` provides various ways) and then press `R`.

Comment: The process is faster how I intend it, if one of the used directories is always the same. Also I don't get it to work with spacemacs for some reason. Using dired-copy I always get the prompt of the target directory even if I have a second dired buffer open.

Comment: You need to set `dired-dwim-target` to `t` to avoid the prompt. Having a shortcut to open the first directory only adds one more keystroke - for me, the flexibility of this solution overshadows any advantage a custom-made solution has.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command that shows files from `your-initial-directory`, and moves/renames the marked/selected files to `your-target-directory`. Tested with `./emacs-helm.sh`.

```
(defvar your-initial-directory "~/Downloads/")
(defvar your-target-directory "~/Documents/")

(defun multiple-rename (_)
  (let ((files (helm-marked-candidates)))
    (helm-dired-action your-target-directory
                       :files files
                       :action 'rename)))

(defclass helm-user-rename (helm-source-ffiles)
  ((action :initform '(("Rename files" . multiple-rename)))))

(defun helm-rename ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'tramp)
  (helm :sources (helm-make-source "Rename files" 'helm-user-rename)
        :input your-initial-directory))
```

1. `M-x helm-rename`
2. `C-SPC` to mark the files you want to rename
3. `RET`

Comment: The script doesn't seem to work, after selecting the first file it just opens a file. I would also like to select the file from the helm sources window (it is fancier).

Comment: You had to press f2 or TAB to select the correct action. In any case, I rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`M-x find-lisp-find-dired` to find files in a directory matching user given regular expression. Please note this command supports unicode on Windows out of box.

Select all files and `M-x dired-do-rename`.

Surely you can use above command in your own code.